# MySQL - Keep one row per minute

Tags: mysql, time, row, minute

I have a very big table in MySQL which contains rows which are timestamped up to milliseconds..

I have a date column which contains dates (called date)

```
2011-01-13
```

and another column which contains the time, in hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds.. (called time)

```
01:11:43.381
```

since I have too many records per minute, is it possible that I keep one entry per minute and delete the other entries in the same minute ? (I could keep the first entry for every minute for example)

How can I do that ? I couldn't find anything online although I searched a bit :(

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to only insert a row each minute?

Comment: Maybe it would, by I imported huge CSV files in the database (like 5 CSV of 5 GB each) and I did quite a lot of processing already, but how would I do what you are saying ?

Comment: Do you have another primary key in this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want with `delete` and aggregation:

```
delete bt
    from bigtable bt join
         (select date, min(time) as time
          from bigtable
          group by date, hour(time), minute(time)
         ) btt
         on btt.date = bt.date and
            hour(bt.time) = hour(btt.time) and
            minute(bt.time) = minute(btt.time) and
            bt.time <> btt.mintime;
```

I am not promising you that this is efficient, but it should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot but what is "t" ? Should I replace it with the name of the table or sth ?

Comment: @adrCoder . . . A typo.  That should be `bt`.

Comment: What is mintime ? I get an error ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'bt.mintime' in 'on clause'

Comment: Should id be bt.time instad of bt.mintime ? Or sth else ? I am getting an error with mintime ...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to delete every rows except first one meet the condition you stated using a simple delete statement below.

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID NOT IN (
        SELECT I FROM (
               SELECT  MIN(PRIMARY_KEY) I, 
                       CONCAT( DATE_FIELD ,' ', SUBSTR(TIME_FIELD, 1, 5)) DT  
               FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY DT) AS X)
```

Basically I are trying to concatenate Date and "Time until minute" and filter the minimum identifier in inner query, Then delete everything except the minimum ID selected.

Important Note: Not inserting unwanted records multiple times will be the best way to solve this issue but the person who asked the question already mentioned thats not an option for him.

Answer (score 0):

Having your date and time split up into two columns can prove exceptionally annoying, so I'd avoid doing that unless you had a compelling technical reason.

As for your minute problem, what you need is a column you can enforce a `UNIQUE` constraint on. The simplest approach is to use a *minute serial*, or the epoch time in seconds divided by 60.

Add a column called `epoch_minute` of type `INT`, give it a `UNIQUE` index constraint, and populate it with the equivalent of that value. Then you can use an `INSERT IGNORE` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` type trigger to handle repetition per minute. This depends on if you want to keep the first record, or the last record for each minute.

You can migrate your old values using the [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function:

```
UPDATE table_name SET epoch_minute = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_column) / 60
```

As an example, given a table called `table_name`, prepare a new table to receive the values that has a unique column constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE _table_name LIKE table_name;
ALTER TABLE _table_name ADD COLUMN epoch_minute INT;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_table_name_epoch_minute ON _table_name (epoch_minute);
```

Then you can use `INSERT IGNORE` to skip duplicates:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO _table_name (column_a, column_b, epoch_minute)
  SELECT column_a, column_b, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_column) / 60
    FROM table_name;
```

Lastly, swap tables:

```
RENAME TABLE table_name TO table_name_old, _table_name to table_name;
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. can you tell me how to create this epoch_minute, especially how to "populate it with the equivalent of that value"? I don't get what I should be putting in it.. I could get the first record for every minute, it doesn't matter very much for me at this point. the reason I separated the date from the time was that my data where in a CSV file like that : ,04-OCT-2012,07:11:12.736, so I couldn't think of a better to way to import them than by separating them

Comment: When you import, combine those two values into one when possible. Dates with English in them are often problematic, so re-writing that to [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format is desirable, it avoids ambiguity. All you need to do is `ALTER TABLE` to introduce the new column. I've amended my answer with more guidance.

Comment: I get an error when I try to create the unique index : mysql> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_table_name_epoch_minute (epoch_minute);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(epoch_minute)' at line 1. Maybe it should be CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_table_name_epoch_minute ON _EuroDollar (epoch_minute); instead ?

Comment: @adrCoder Yeah, that'd be it. My mistake.